# Ggplot way to seperate geom_point from geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot in which I want to connect points together by a grey line. I was wondering is there a way to add a border around the points so that the line is touching their border or isn't even touching the point as opposed to going right into the centre of the point. I'm using ggplot.

[image]

I've included some sample data for anyone who wants to play around with it.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
                  Category = c("x","y","x","y","x","y"),
                  N = c(500,540,470,500,480,520))
```

I've also included my ggplot code used to make the plot above

```
df %>% 
  arrange(N) %>%
  mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Name, N)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Category)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1,size = 2,colour = "black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("green","cyan")) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Name), colour = "grey", alpha = 1) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    legend.position = "none")
```

Edit:

As shown below in the comments switching the line to before the points work and produces the following:

[image]

Comment: You could just put `geom_line` ahead of `geom_point` and it should fix your problem

Comment: Wow I expected such a complex solution to this lmao. Thank you very much erocoar. Why is this the case?

Comment: The geoms are drawn in order of appearance, so the points are simply drawn last and cover the line endings :)

Comment: Brilliant thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your plot is reproducible with unique letters for `Name`. To fit a vertical line, `Name` requires unique 'pairs' of letters. In your call to `ggplot()`, `Name` is mapped onto the x-axis *and* also passed to the group aesthetic, which produces a line between two points at the *same* x-value. For example, your data frame should look something like the following:

```
  Name Category   N
1    A        x 500
2    A        y 540
3    B        x 470
4    B        y 500
5    C        x 480
6    C        y 520
```

Note, each group consists of two observations, which should only vary along the vertical dimension.

I imagine your data frame was corrected to account for this, but it isn't clear from the code you supplied. It appears @erocoar already addressed your principal concern in the comments. It is a simple matter of precedence with respect to the `geom_` layers.

I reproduced your plot using a new data frame. Remember, we must have more than one observation per group for this work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 2),  # unique pairs (two observations per group)
  Category = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"),
  N = c(500, 540, 470, 500, 480, 520)
  )

df |> 
  arrange(N) |>
  mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))) |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = N)) +
      geom_line(aes(group = Name), colour = "grey", alpha = 1) +  # feeding Name to the group aesthetic
      geom_point(aes(color = Category)) +
      geom_point(shape = 1,size = 2,colour = "black") +
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("green", "cyan")) +
      theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image: two observations per pair]

Comment: Thanks Thomas apologies the dataframe wasn't 100% clear thank you for explaining that